# Can you use more than one martial maneuver in a single round?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, martial

At first I thought you could only use one martial maneuver a round, but after looking through Tome of Battle, I can't seem to find that explicitly stated anywhere. Is there really such a restriction and I'm just not finding it, or can you use multiple maneuvers provided their action requirements allow it (i.e. a move action Boost in the same round as a standard action Strike)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

There are only a few requirements for using a maneuver:

- You meet its prerequisites (including Initiator Level)
- You know it
- You readied it
- You’ve been granted it, if a Crusader
- You have not expended it since the last time you recovered
- You can and do use the action required for it

As you say, this means you can use more than one per round. In fact, that is exactly how the system is intended to work: while in a Stance (you should basically always be in a Stance, unless you were ambushed while sleeping or something), you use a Boost to power yourself up, and then bash your enemy with a Strike. If you use a Counter, you give up your Boost in the following round. If you want to change Stances, that replaces your Boost and you can’t do it the same round as a Counter.

Comment: Ah, that's good. Now the Swordsage class feature of being able to apply two boosts at once suddenly becomes more interesting.

Comment: @Cobalt It's pretty solid and the Swordsage class itself has a lot to recommend it (high skills, two good saves, and most of all the unmatched maneuver at every level), but sadly not as good the Warblade's Dual Stance.

Comment: I noticed Master of Nine lets you use Dual Stance, too, but the qualification requirements don't make it seem all that worthwhile.

Comment: @Cobalt It's different, in that you can only use it 2 rounds/day/level. Still good, though, and Mot9 has other things to recommend it. But yes, overall, it's *very* painful to enter. You can help yourself out a lot by (if allowed) using Unarmed Swordsage (Improved Unarmed Strike) and taking a level of Cleric (Blind-fight feat from Darkness Domain, *Spell Compendium*, plus lots of other goodies). Desert Wind Dodge is better than Dodge, anyway. A Swordsage was taking Adaptive Style anyway, and Improved Initiative is not awful.

Comment: Silly me, forgot to mention Time Domain for Improved Initiative. So Desert Wind Dodge is the only feat you have to take with normal feats. Imp. Unarmed Strike from Unarmed Swordsage, Blind-fight and Imp. Initiative from Cleric, and Adaptive Strike is basically must-have for Swordsages anyway.

Comment: @KRyan "If you use a Counter, you give up your Boost in the following round". What do you mean? I didn't see anything stating this in Tome of Battle.

Comment: @Momonga-sama Because that’s how immediate actions work, they use the next round’s swift action.

Answer (score 1):

Each maneuver has a starting required action (in most cases it is a Swift Action). You can do only one Swift or Immediate Action each round.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If you haven't, please check out the [Tour], and when you get 20 rep, feel free to join the [Chat].